# Custom colors for Algebra of Graphics Package (Julia)

Tags: julia

I want to set custom colors for each of the following datasets (perhaps those from the color package). In this case, coloring should be done by the name of the data in column :nam.

```
using DataFrames
using Colors
using AlgebraOfGraphics
using CairoMakie
```

```
df1 = DataFrame( nam = ["a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c"], num = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,1] )
dataIn = data(df1)*mapping(:1,:2)*visual(BoxPlot)
draw(dataIn)
```

Also I wonder how I could set custom color gradient in this case somehow:

```
df2 = DataFrame(t = [1,2,3,4,5,6], x = [1,1,1,1,1,1], y = [2,3,4,5,6,7])
dataIn2 = data(df2)*mapping(:x,:y,color = :t) 
draw(dataIn2)
```

Also how would I pass a color from the Color package into a plot in a way something like:

```
df2 = DataFrame(t = [1,2,3,4,5,6], x = [1,1,1,1,1,1], y = [2,3,4,5,6,7])
dataIn2 = data(df2)*mapping(:x,:y,color = colorFromColorPackage???) 
draw(dataIn2)
```

I tried using parse.(Colorant, "color from ColorPackage") which did not work.

Comment: Do you mind writing a [stand-alone example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including any `using` statements and function definitions?

Comment: @AshlinHarris Added using statements.

Comment: [This post on the Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/styling-algebraofgraphics-boxplots/65335/12) seems relevant.